# Is it possible to force Linux to invalidate virtual memory after free

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, virtual-memory

On Windows, I have noticed that trying to dereference a pointer to recently freed memory results in a crash, trapped by Visual Studio stating that the memory is invalid. This is as expected. However, executing the same application and code path leading to dereferencing a pointer to recently freed memory does not immediately cause a crash in Linux. This suggests to me that the Linux kernel (or GNU C++ run-time) does not invalidate freed memory very quickly, even on debug builds. The application takes much longer to crash. Is this the case? If so, can I force the memory to be unmapped more quickly? If not then what's going on?

Comment: I don't know.  Whenever this comes up, I stop doing the UB instead of trying to understand exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried http://valgrind.org/? It's purpose is to help track down problems such as the one you've described.

Comment: +1; Valgrind is awesome.  Ridiculously complex, perhaps, but it is an excellent tool.

Comment: Yep, I am using Valrgind. The memcheck tool clearly reports the read from the invalid memory. I'm just curious about the apparent difference between the treatment of freed memory by Windows and Linux.

Comment: Well, AFAIK behavior isn't defined, so no wonder it differs on different systems (or even compilers, compiler versions, compiler options).

Answer (score 2):

Most implementations of `new`/`delete` do not return memory
immediately to the system, or at least don't return smaller
blocks.  I'm rather surprised that your code crashed under
Windows simply by dereferencing a pointer to the memory; are you
sure you didn't do more than that (e.g. use the value you read
through the pointer).

How big was the block?  Many implementations use different
strategies depending on the size of the block, and will free
very large blocks immediately.  (IIRC, Linux will do a `mmap`
immediately for very large blocks, and unmap it immediately when
you free it.  Of course, if you reallocate memory between the
free and dereferencing the pointer, it's possible that the
address is in the newly allocated space, and it won't crash.)

In the end: the granularity of mapping is the page, and you
cannot expect the allocator to block up a complete page for each
allocation, just so that it can invalidate the memory
immediately on deallocation.  (A page is probably at least 4K,
and you don't want to loose 4K address space each time you
allocate 16 bytes.)  Short of tracking all memory accesses (like
ValGrand or Purify), and running a lot slower, the only
alternative is to use garbage collection, to ensure that the
memory isn't reallocated as long as there is a pointer to it,
and overwrite it completely on deallocation (i.e. in `delete`
or `free`) with values that are likely to cause problems if used
(`0xDEADBEEF`, or something like that).  And even then, you're
not really guaranteed that you'll crash—`0xDEADBEEF` could
be a valid value for what you think you're reading.  (But this
does allow e.g. setting a flag in the constructor, resetting it
in the destructor, and testing it in each function.  For code
that has to be actively defensive.)